# Snap: inner/outer loops with heist

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am not sure if I phrased the question in the title correctly but here is the situation..
I need to create a dynamic table with heist when table fields (schema) are only available at run time.
So usually, when the schema is known at compile, I would do something like this:

```
<table>
  <row-splice>
    <tr>
      <td> <field1/> </td>
      <td> <field2/> </td>
      <td> <field3/> </td>
    </tr>
  </row-splice>
</table>
```

That is when I know the number of fields and their names at compile time.
I understand how to process all that in the handler with 'runChildrenWith', 'mapSplices' and so on ...

Now I am in a situation when the number of fields and schema are available only at run time.
So the heist template, as I understand it, would look like this:

```
<table>
  <row-splice>
    <tr>
      <field-splice>
      <td> <field/> </td>
      </field-splice>
    </tr>
  </row-splice>
</table>
```

I am really stuck with how to implement it within the handler. I assume I would need to do 'mapSplices' twice - one inside the other, correct? So, empirically speaking, that would be an inner and outer loop/map, right?

How would I do this within handler??

Thanks.

Update:

Forgot to mention that schema can be retrieved at run time from the DB and available as:

```
Table { tableName   :: Text
      , tableFields :: [Text]
      }
```

But it is not really needed as data comes from schema-less mongodb and converted to Map:

```
fromList [("FieldName1","Value1"),("FieldName2","Value2"),("FieldName3","Value3")]
```

Update2:

I tried suggested examples with no luck I just get all my data in a single column.
All I need is a simple inner and outer loop to generate fields and rows dynamically.
It cannot be simpler then this:

```
<% @rows.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
  <% row.each do |field| %>
    <td> <%= field %> </td> 
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Update3:

I finally cracked it after a long weekend rest ...
Here is the example. it is mongodb specific and I literally just copied and pasted it.
But if someone gets stuck with inner/outer loops it would be helpful, I suppose.

```
showTableH :: AppHandler ()
showTableH = do
  table <- liftIO $ fetchTable tname
  docs <- liftIO $ getColList tname
  let rowSplice doc = mapSplices (\f -> fieldSplice $ T.pack $ at f doc) (tableFields table)
    where fieldSplice field = runChildrenWithText [("field", field)]
  let listRowsSplice = mapSplices (\d -> runChildrenWith [("fields", rowSplice d)]) docs
  heistLocal (bindSplices [("rows", listRowsSplice)]) $ render "show-table"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key here is using mapSplices along with runChildrenWith.  I think it would look something like this:

```
rowSplice = do
    rows <- lift getRowsFromDB
    mapSplices (\row -> runChildrenWith [("field-splice", fieldSplice row)]) rows
fieldSplice rowId = do
    fields <- lift $ getFieldsFromDB rowId
    mapSplices (\f -> runChildrenWith [("field", fieldToText f)]) fields
```

Comment: Thank you very much, still does not work though .. I've played with it for a day - no luck. I obviously do something wrong. In your example, as I can see, there is only the internal "loop" generating fields within a single row. Now, the internal "loop" should run withing the outer loop which generates the rows within the table. I just don't know how to connect the two together. So internal 'mapSplices' should create a row and external 'mapSplices' should create a table.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the answer.  Try that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I kind of cracked it as well... Even your first example helped me a lot, I got the idea of how to nest the 'runChildren' functions. Thanks once again.